# How can I use Python to get the system hostname?

Tags: python, hostname

I'm writing a chat program for a local network. I would like be able to identify computers and get the user-set computer name with Python.

Answer (score 1444, accepted):

Use [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) and its [`gethostname()`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) functionality. This will get the `hostname` of the computer where the Python interpreter is running:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

Comment: And note that for the FQDN you can use `socket.getfqdn()`

Comment: Just curious what's the difference between socket.gethostname() and os.uname()[1] or platform.uname()[1]

Comment: is this portable?

Comment: how to get a hostname without DNS suffix?

Comment: @iEfimoff On some systems (rhel 7. 9 x86_64) socket.gethostname still returns the full name with FQDN.  I used sysName = socket.gethostname().split(".")[0] to get just the short hostname into a variable named 'sysName'

Comment: How is this not at the top?

Answer (score 486):

Both of these are pretty portable:

```
import platform
platform.node()

import socket
socket.gethostname()
```

Any solutions using the `HOST` or `HOSTNAME` environment variables are not portable.  Even if it works on your system when you run it, it may not work when run in special environments such as cron.

Comment: Well, semi-portable.  On some platforms, platform.node() gives the fqdn and on others, only the hostname

Comment: `python -m timeit "import socket; socket.gethostname()"
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.3 usec per loop`

Comment: `python -m timeit "import platform; platform.node()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.74 usec per loop`

Comment: @BelowtheRadar don't worry, I usually only call either of these once per script.

Comment: platform.node() is even faster than os.getenv.  gethostname isn't even a contender.  But if time isn't a factor: `import os, platform; os.getenv('HOSTNAME', os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME', platform.node())).split('.')[0]` should be cross-platform and support environment variables if they exist - which permits some user control in exigent circumstances, eg `HOSTNAME=correct python xyz.py`

Comment: @raindog308 : how does `socket.gethostname` compare to `platform.node` in terms of the inconsistency you describe?

Comment: Does anyone know why `platform.node()` is so much faster than others?

Comment: @codeforester `platform.node()` returns a cached value. `socket.gethostname()` does not. Example: `import platform, socket, subprocess; p = lambda: print(platform.node(), socket.gethostname()); p(); subprocess.run(['sudo', 'hostnamectl', 'set-hostname', foo']); p()`. While both functions return the same correct value on the first call, after the hostname has been changed `platform.node()` still returns the old value.

Answer (score 187):

You will probably load the os module anyway, so another suggestion would be:

```
import os
myhost = os.uname()[1]
```

Comment: +1 for a solution using `os` module. Not portable and not really accurate, but handy anyway.

Comment: os.uname is not supported on Windows:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os#os.uname

Comment: You can also do os.uname().nodename to make it a bit more obvious in 3.3+

Comment: An answer below gives the similar looking `platform.uname()[1]`, which DOES work on Windows.

Comment: @fantabolous You probably shouldn't use positional words like "below" as answers may have shifted during landing ;)

Comment: why is this not protable?

Comment: Since `os.uname()` actually returns a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) one can also do the more descriptive `myhost = os.uname().nodename`

Comment: @Charlie Parker: It's not portable since it doesn't work on windows.  `platform.uname()[1]` or `platform.node()` should work well everywhere.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'

Answer (score 79):

What about :

```
import platform

h = platform.uname()[1]
```

Actually you may want to have a look to all the result in `platform.uname()`

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu and Windows for me. Thanks! 

Comment: `platform.uname().node` is a bit more verbose than `platform.uname()[1]`, I assume it was introduced around the same time as the `os.uname` equivalent [mentioned in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname#comment48417170_15394250).

Comment: This should be the same as `platform.node()`

Answer (score 65):

`os.getenv('HOSTNAME')` and `os.environ['HOSTNAME']` don't always work. In cron jobs and WSDL, HTTP HOSTNAME isn't set. Use this instead:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
```

It always (even on Windows) returns a fully qualified host name, even if you defined a short alias in */etc/hosts*.

If you defined an alias in */etc/hosts* then `socket.gethostname()` will return the alias. `platform.uname()[1]` does the same thing.

I ran into a case where the above didn't work. This is what I'm using now:

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname().find('.')>=0:
    name=socket.gethostname()
else:
    name=socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
```

It first calls gethostname to see if it returns something that looks like a host name, if not it uses my original solution.

Comment: you probably want `socket.getfqdn()`, though it is not what the OP asks

Comment: `socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())` on my machine (which is running FreeBSD) returns `('localhost', ['my-machine-name', 'my-machine-namelocaldomain'], ['::1'])`, so returning the first element just returns `localhost`. (Meanwhile, `socket.gethostname()` returns `my-machine-name` for me.)

Answer (score 52):

From at least [python >= 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.uname):

You can use the field `nodename` and avoid using array indexing:

```
os.uname().nodename
```

Although, even the documentation of [os.uname](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.uname) suggests using `socket.gethostname()`

Comment: According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.uname), `os.uname` is available only on "recent flavors of Unix"

Comment: @CharlesPlager Worked for me in Python 3.8.6, RHEL7 container running in OpenShift

Comment: Not portable, no windows support

Answer (score 25):

If I'm correct, you're looking for the socket.gethostname function:

```
>> import socket
>> socket.gethostname()
'terminus'
```

Answer (score 16):

You have to execute this line of code

```
sock_name = socket.gethostname()
```

And then you can use the name to find the addr :

```
print(socket.gethostbyname(sock_name))
```

Comment: this approach returns just ip for me

Answer (score 14):

`socket.gethostname()` could do

Answer (score 11):

To get fully qualified hostname use socket.getfqdn()

```
import socket

print socket.getfqdn()
```

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately sometimes this just returns `localhost`, and not even the hostname as returned by `socket.gethostname()`.

Answer (score 9):

On some systems, the hostname is set in the environment. If that is the case for you, the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) can pull it out of the environment via [os.getenv](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getenv). For example, if HOSTNAME is the environment variable containing what you want, the following will get it:

```
import os
system_name = os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
```

Update: As noted in the comments, this doesn't always work, as not everyone's environment is set up this way. I believe that at the time I initially answered this I was using this solution as it was the first thing I'd found in a web search and it worked for me at the time. Due to the lack of portability I probably wouldn't use this now. However, I am leaving this answer for reference purposes. FWIW, it does eliminate the need for other imports if your environment has the system name and you are already importing the os module. Test it - if it doesn't work in all the environments in which you expect your program to operate, use one of the other solutions provided.

Comment: That returns "None" for me.  According to the link you posted, that means the variable 'HOSTNAME' doesn't exist... :-/

Comment: @John:  Are you on Windows?  It worked for me on a Linux box, but I get None on Windows also.

Comment: @MuhiaNJoroge: I think that depends on your implementation/installation.  When I wrote that answer I was on a Red Hat box and it worked.  Now I'm on Ubuntu and it doesn't work.  I've modified the answer.

Comment: Not work in lenovo NAS, return None. Now i'm using import socket
print(socket.gethostname())

Comment: @RuiMartins: As I said, it doesn't seem to work everywhere. Glad you found something that works.

Comment: This is often a bash variable which you'd need to re-export for Python to access, e.g. start Python with `HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME python`

Answer (score 7):

I needed the name of the PC to use in my PyLog conf file, and the socket library is not available, but os library is.

For **Windows** I used:

```
os.getenv('COMPUTERNAME', 'defaultValue')
```

Where defaultValue is a string to prevent None being returned

Comment: COMPUTERNAME is a very Microsoft only environment variable and therefor not portable.

Comment: Yes, but it does work for M.S. systems, and if it fits, it works. Many times people here get too entwined on speed or platform independence when practicality and the question render them irrelevant.

Comment: @BillKidd OP mentions Windows, OS X, and Linux in the question, so needing system portability is a very reasonable assumption.

Comment: @BillKidd While in general it is true that you should avoid premature optimization or portability, not using a readily available and and arguably more maintainable solution because it is more portable is going to the opposite extreme.

Comment: socket.gethostname() is better than os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']. Because  os.environ['COMPUTERNAME'] do not support long PC name after I used it.