# How can I get Docker Linux container information from within the container itself?

Tags: linux, docker

I would like to make my `docker containers` aware of their configuration, the same way you can get information about EC2 instances through metadata.

I can use (provided `docker` is listening on port `4243`)

```
curl http://172.17.42.1:4243/containers/$HOSTNAME/json
```

to get some of its data, but would like to know if there is a better way at least the get the full ID of the container, because `HOSTNAME` is actually shortened to 12 characters and docker seems to perform a "best match" on it.

Also, how can I get the external IP of the docker host (other than accessing the EC2 metadata, which is specific to AWS)

Comment: BEWARE: you should read this https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html before attempting any of the approaches below that attempt to use /var/run/docker.sock inside the container

Comment: In case @harschware's link breaks, I'll summarise here: By giving the container access to `/var/run/docker.sock`, it is possible (trivial) to break out of the containment provided by docker and gain access to the host machine. Obviously this is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the same information in a *windows* docker container if the --hostname argument was used with the run command so that simply running 'hostname' no longer gives you the containerid?

Comment: Exposing docker daemon api to containers is a very bad approach in terms of security. Because compromised container can access docker and do anything it wants. There should be some separate API for non private info fetching only.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I've found out that the container id can be found in /proc/self/cgroup

So you can get the id with :

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope" | head -n 1 | sed "s/docker-\(.*\).scope/\\1/"
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a bit, this works for me in Docker 1.4.1

`cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "docker" | sed s/\\//\\n/g | tail -1`

Comment: For docker 1.6.2 I had to use: `cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep 'docker' | sed 's/^.*\///' | tail -n1`

Comment: For docker 1.8 and beyond that file seems to be available under /proc/1/cgroup.

Comment: Aaaaand Docker 1.12: `cat /proc/1/cgroup | grep 'docker/' | tail -1 | sed 's/^.*\///' | cut -c 1-12`

Comment: both `/proc/1` and `/proc/self` should work. Actually, `/proc/self` is pointing to the process running `cat /proc/self`. This process is in the same cgroup as the pid 1 process. :)

Comment: I kind of like `basename "$(cat /proc/1/cpuset)"` and `basename "$(head /proc/1/cgroup)"`

Comment: Not working for me in 1.12.3. `/proc/self/mountinfo` does include the ID, however.

Comment: Or rather, `cgroup` works under most conditions, but not under some conditions I have yet to identify (whereas `mountinfo` seems to work consistently).

Comment: I like the basic method, although I'm guessing the format of /proc/self/cgroup may change between version. This worked on my version: head -1 /proc/self/cgroup | cut -d: -f3 | sed -e's&/docker/&&' (version 17.03.1-ce)

Comment: Maybe this: API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12))

Comment: Or: cut -d/ -f3 /proc/1/cpuset (based on smets.kevin above, thx) I only see one line in this /proc file, can there be several? When?

Comment: In the future, if cgroup namespace and cgroup v2 are used in docker, this method may not work anymore.

Comment: How do we do this for a Windows container?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working in Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6.

Comment: Doesn't work on `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`

Comment: Alternatively for me this worked, `cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "\/docker\/" | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*\/docker\///' | cut -c1-12`. I saw the container ID information when I did `cat`, then it was about extracting the 12-character ID from the complete ID.

Comment: I used `cat /proc/1/cpuset | head -n 1 | sed "s/\/docker\/\(.*\)/\\1/"`

Comment: `cat /proc/self/cgroup | sed -n '1s/.*docker-\(.*\).scope/\1/p'`

Comment: with cgroup v2 in use this won't work anymore as @JingQiu said. there is another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816329/how-to-get-docker-container-id-from-within-the-container-with-cgroup-v2/70685581#70685581

Answer (score 126):

Unless overridden, the hostname seems to be the short container id in Docker 1.12

```
root@d2258e6dec11:/project# cat /etc/hostname
d2258e6dec11
```

Externally

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d2258e6dec11        300518d26271        "bash"              5 minutes ago       

$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e, experimental
```

Comment: Yup this made it easy to pull the info in nodejs for me. `const os = require('os'); console.log(os.hostname());`

Comment: To get the hostname that matches the Container Id in Java, use `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`.

Comment: Sometimes it's simpler to read the value of the environment variable `$HOSTNAME` (for example in shell scripts).

Comment: on a windows container, the equivalent is the `COMPUTERNAME` env var

Comment: If working in Windows though, be sure to lowercase the COMPUTERNAME value before passing into the Docker Engine API.

Comment: To do this [from python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271755/913098): `import socket; socket.gethostname()`

Answer (score 52):

A comment by [madeddie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container#comment68411936_25729598) looks most elegant to me:

```
CID=$(basename $(cat /proc/1/cpuset))
```

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate what this actually does. DOes it still work if hostname was overriden for that container by the user? does it need filesystem access outside of the container?

Comment: excellent! works when `network_mode=host`, use  `export SCID=${CID:0:12}` for to get the short container id - as displayed in `docker ps`.

Comment: In WSL and Arch, the `cpuset` is `/` so to make it work in WSL and Docker,  I remove the trailing slash with the below command:
`export _CID=${$(basename $(cat /proc/1/cpuset))//\/}` and 
`export _SCID=${_CID:0:12}` That way my shell commands can check if the `_CID` variable is set

Answer (score 37):

You can communicate with docker from inside of a container using unix socket via Docker Remote API:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/

In a container, you can find out a shortedned docker id by examining `$HOSTNAME` env var.
According to doc, there is a small chance of collision, I think that for small number of container, you do not have to worry about it. I don't know how to get full id directly.

You can inspect container similar way as outlined in **banyan** answer:

```
GET /containers/4abbef615af7/json HTTP/1.1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
         "Id": "4abbef615af7......  ",
         "Created": "2013.....",
         ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can transfer docker id to the container in a file.
The file is located on "mounted volume" so it is transfered to container:

```
docker run -t -i -cidfile /mydir/host1.txt -v /mydir:/mydir ubuntu /bin/bash
```

The docker id (shortened) will be in file /mydir/host1.txt in the container.

Comment: Thanks but this is the same approach I am using anyway, and will break if you set the hostname with -h when you run docker.

Comment: @Alessandro I have added information about -cidfile parameter to docker run. It may help you to pass docker id to the container instead of using $HOSTNAME.

Comment: Great! Yes that is something I could use! Thank you!

Comment: Oddly, in 1.11.2 it seems `env` does not list `HOSTNAME`, but `echo $HOSTNAME` works.

Comment: This doesn't work at all, and your URL is broken and now redirects to the wrong documentation. `requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/containers/1d26a841bf07/json': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///containers/1d26a841bf07/json?`

Answer (score 24):

**WARNING:** You should understand [the security risks of this method](https://www.lvh.io/posts/dont-expose-the-docker-socket-not-even-to-a-container.html) before you consider it. [John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container#comment83419495_20995351)'s summary of the risk:

> By giving the container access to `/var/run/docker.sock`, it is [trivially easy] to break out of the containment provided by docker and gain access to the host machine. Obviously this is potentially dangerous.

---

Inside the container, the dockerId is your hostname.
So, you could:

- install the [docker-io package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/docker.io) in your container with the same version as the host
- start it with `--volume
  /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged`
- finally, run: `docker inspect $(hostname)` inside the container

**Avoid this. Only do it if you understand the risks and have a clear mitigation for the risks.**

Comment: I suspect this won't work if the docker run `--hostname` option has been used.

Comment: If `--hostname` is set you can use a combination from this answer and the comment from @Jay Taylor in the accepted answer: `docker inspect $(cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep 'docker' | sed 's/^.*\///' | tail -n1)` to get all information about the running container.

Comment: could you put a reference to docker-io?

Comment: I assume its https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-io/ but that was just what Google told me and perhaps isn't what you meant.

Comment: What would that mitigation be?

Answer (score 24):

This will get the full container id from within a container:

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep "cpu:/" | sed 's/\([0-9]\):cpu:\/docker\///g'
```

Answer (score 20):

To make it simple,

1. Container ID is your host name inside docker
2. Container information is available inside /proc/self/cgroup

To get host name,

```
hostname
```

or

```
uname -n
```

or

```
cat /etc/host
```

Output can be redirected to any file & read back from application
E.g.: `# hostname > /usr/src//hostname.txt`

Answer (score 14):

I've found that in 17.09 there is a simplest way to do it within docker container:

```
$ cat /proc/self/cgroup | head -n 1 | cut -d '/' -f3
4de1c09d3f1979147cd5672571b69abec03d606afcc7bdc54ddb2b69dec3861c
```

Or like it has already been told, a shorter version with

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
4de1c09d3f19
```

Or simply:

```
$ hostname
4de1c09d3f19
```

Answer (score 9):

Docker sets the hostname to the container ID by default, but users can override this with `--hostname`. Instead, inspect `/proc`:

```
$ more /proc/self/cgroup
14:name=systemd:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
13:pids:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
12:hugetlb:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
11:net_prio:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
10:perf_event:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
9:net_cls:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
8:freezer:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
7:devices:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
6:memory:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
5:blkio:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
4:cpuacct:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
3:cpu:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
2:cpuset:/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
1:name=openrc:/docker
```

Here's a handy one-liner to extract the container ID:

```
$ grep "memory:/" < /proc/self/cgroup | sed 's|.*/||'
7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
```

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 places that I see that might work so far, each have advantages & disadvantages:

1. `echo $HOSTNAME` or `hostname`
2. `cat /proc/self/cgroup`
3. `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`

`$HOSTNAME` is easy, but it is partial, and it will also be **overwritten** to pod name by K8s.

`/proc/self/cgroup` seems working with **cgroupV1** but won't be there hosted in **cgroupV2**.

`/proc/self/mountinfo` will still have the container id for **cgroupV2**, however, the mount point will have different values by different container runtimes.

- For example, in docker engine, the value looks like:

```
678 655 254:1 /docker/containers/7a0144cee1256c539fab790199527b7051aff1b603ebcf7ed3fd436440ef3b3a/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/vda1 rw
```

- In `ContainerD` (K8s default engine lately), it looks like:

```
1733 1729 0:35 /kubepods/besteffort/pod3272f253-be44-4a82-a541-9083e68cf99f/7a0144cee1256c539fab790199527b7051aff1b603ebcf7ed3fd436440ef3b3a /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime master:17 - cgroup cgroup rw,blkio
```

Also, the biggest problem for all above is that they are all implementations, there's no abstraction and they all could be changed over time.

There is an effort to make it standard and I think it is worth watching:

https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1105

Comment: For newer Docker versions on hosts using cgroupV2 this (mountinfo) seem to be the only viable option.

Comment: Thanks! Most answers above are actually even more brittle or make little sense as they rely on the hostname being the container ID among others. This is a fairly detailed explanation of the problem and some ways around it (that work for now).

Answer (score 5):

Some posted solutions have stopped working due to changes in the format of `/proc/self/cgroup`. Here is a single GNU grep command that should be a bit more robust to format changes:

```
grep -o -P -m1 'docker.*\K[0-9a-f]{64,}' /proc/self/cgroup
```

For reference, here are snippits of /proc/self/cgroup from inside docker containers that have been tested with this command:

Linux 4.4:

```
11:pids:/system.slice/docker-cde7c2bab394630a42d73dc610b9c57415dced996106665d427f6d0566594411.scope
...
1:name=systemd:/system.slice/docker-cde7c2bab394630a42d73dc610b9c57415dced996106665d427f6d0566594411.scope
```

Linux 4.8 - 4.13:

```
11:hugetlb:/docker/afe96d48db6d2c19585572f986fc310c92421a3dac28310e847566fb82166013
...
1:name=systemd:/docker/afe96d48db6d2c19585572f986fc310c92421a3dac28310e847566fb82166013
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the "problem" with all of the above is that it depends upon a certain implementation convention either of docker itself or its implementation and how that interacts with cgroups and /proc, and *not* via a committed, public, API, protocol or convention as part of the OCI specs.

Hence these solutions are "brittle" and likely to break when least expected when implementations change, or conventions are overridden by user configuration.

container and image ids *should* be injected into the r/t environment by the component that initiated the container instance, if for no other reason than
to permit code running therein to use that information to uniquely identify themselves for logging/tracing etc...

just my $0.02, YMMV...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command line to identify the current container ID (tested with docker 1.9).

```
awk -F"-|/." '/1:/ {print $3}' /proc/self/cgroup
```

Then, a little request to Docker API (you can share /var/run/docker.sock) to retrieve all informations.

Comment: awk -F"-|/." '/1:/ {print $3}' /proc/self/cgroup

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[:/]' '(($4 == "docker") && (lastId != $NF)) { lastId = $NF; print $NF; }' /proc/self/cgroup
```

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, if you have the pid of the container and want to get the docker id of that container, a good way is to use nsenter in combination with the sed magic above:

`nsenter -n -m -t pid -- cat /proc/1/cgroup | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope" | head -n 1 | sed "s/docker-\(.*\).scope/\\1/"`

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of docker does not have the information in cgroup.
I recommend binding /var/run/docker.sock and access the information via a library or curl.

`curl -s --unix-socket /run/docker.sock http://docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/json`