# how to get container name from inside? docker.io

Tags: containers, docker

How can I get docker's container name from inside the container?

I can't use "inspect" because I have to use a script from inside the container to get information from a JSON url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker, how to get container information from within the container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mean the Container ID its available in the env as the hostname variable. It should be interchangeable with the name for most operations.

```
env
HOSTNAME=5252eb24b296
TERM=xterm
....

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5252eb24b296        ubuntu:14.04        "bash"              23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds                           test
```

Comment: Though, this way will not work in two cases. First - if hostname is explicitly specified with `--hostname` flag, second - when using `--net=host` mode.

Comment: Also, not if the container name is specified with `--name`. (Assuming that what you want is the friendly name, and not the automatically assigned name).

Answer (score 9):

you can use `cut -c9- < /proc/1/cpuset`

Comment: surprisingly this is the simplest answer which get's what most people might need

Comment: gives me the id

Answer (score 8):

If you want the container name rather than container id you can do a reverse DNS lookup on eth0 of the container.

`` dig -x `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet' | awk '{print $2}'` +short | cut -d'.' -f1 ``

This gives you the friendly name rather than the id.

UPDATE: Only works if you have `ifconfig` and `dig` and other tools installed.

Comment: One might want to mention this (obviously) only works if ifconfig, dig, etc. are actually installed inside the docker image. Which is often **not** the case, espacially in Alpine-based or stripped-down images.

Answer (score 6):

I think, most reliable way to use combination of `--cidfile` and `-v` options.

`docker run --cidfile=/tmp/container.id -v /tmp/container.id:/tmp/container.id ${IMAGE}`

If you will start container this way, you can read `/tmp/container.id` from inside of your container.

Comment: Sadly not working for docker-compose https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/940 It was silently closed by Shin

Answer (score 2):

if you have docker inside container,
(you need to bind -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock)
and the hostname was not modified you can get it via:
`docker inspect -f '{{.Name}}' $HOSTNAME`

but this solution can be used only in edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of docker-compose we had a / in front of the hostname so using cut we removed that.

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}' "$HOSTNAME" | cut -c 2-
```