# docker compose scale two services as group

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scale, environment

I'm new to Docker compose and looking for a way to scale two services together at the same time and set an environments for each replica.

This docker-compose example for what I want to achieve

```
version: '3'

networks:
  my-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

services:
  my-service:
    image: service:latest
    networks:
      - my-network
  my-client:
    image: client:latest
    depends_on:
      - my-service
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      SERVICE_IP: "my-service:1234"
```

when I run this with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up` everything works fine.

Now I want to scale the two services such that every `my-client` has one **unique** `my-service`, I tried to do `docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up --scale my-service=10 --scale my-client=10`

What happened is some of the `my-client` has the same `my-service` IP because of `SERVICE_IP: "my-service:1234"` and didn't **uniquely** assign the IP's as one to one. which left some `my-service` without any client and some `my-service` witch many clients.

**My current workaround**

since docker compose create services when scale which has names like *<service_name>*#, I try to do reverse DNS lookup for each `my-client` to match with one `my-service`

```
version: '3'

networks:
  my-network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16

services:
  my-service:
    image: service:latest
    networks:
      - my-network
  my-client:
    image: client:latest
    depends_on:
      - my-service
    networks:
      - my-network
    command: sh -c "export MY_IP=$$(ifconfig | grep '172.20' | awk '{print $$2}' | cut -d ':' -f2) && export MY_SERVICE=$$(host $$MY_IP | awk '{print $$5}' | cut -d '.' -f1 | sed 's/my-client/my-serivce/g') && export SERVICE_IP=$$MY_SERVICE:1234 && my-client
```

I removed `SERVICE_IP: "my-service:1234"` and got `my-client` domainname using reverse DNS, then replace *my-client* from the domain to *my-service* which will map one client for one service.

inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64790547/14053770

**TL;TR**

I want to assign environments with a service name,container name, ... that can scale **uniquely** as group one to one, without this workaround.