# Printing docker container id in Spring boot app

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app in docker. This app is scaled up and can run on multiple containers. I want the app to print the container id . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

A `docker ps` would display it.
Or a `docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" <container_name>`

But if your goal is to access that id from the container itself, see "[Docker, how to get container information from within the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995351/6309)"

For instance:

```
awk -F"-|\." '/1:/ {print $3}' /proc/self/cgroup
```

If you can put that information in a file at the start of your [Spring Boot app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/), then that same application can access that file, read it and display said information.