# Dynamically get a running container id/name created by docker run command

Tags: linux, bash, docker

So I'm trying to run the following shell script which requires the container id/name of the container (in which the script would be run) dynamically.

One way could be to do **docker ps** and then getting the Container Id, but that won't be dynamic.

So is there a way to do this dynamically?

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec <container id/name> /bin/bash -c "useradd -m <username> -p <password>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker, how to get container information from within the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container)

Comment: I did not get the usecase. Do you want to know from inside container what is it's ID/name, or just know ID of a container created by `docker run`?
Also, if you are inside container already, maybe there is no need to run docker exec? And if you are outside, you anyway need to know name/id to exec.

Answer (score 32):

You can give your container a specific name when running it using --name option.

```
docker run --name mycontainer ...
```

Then your exec command can use the specified name:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer ...
```

Comment: Then it would be restricted to that container only. But I could be running the script from any container.

Comment: @Nobita if you have 2 different containers running, how would you know (manually) which container you want the script to run in. Is it the container image, or something else?

Comment: Consider we have multiple containers for the same image and we don't know which container we are running the script from (as all of them are identical)

Comment: You're not answering the question. How *would* you know which one to connect to?  A common trick is `docker ps -l -q` which gets you the id of the latest container you started but obviously that's not necessarily what you want here.

Answer (score 22):

You can start your container and store the container id inside a variable like so:

```sh
container_id=$(docker run -it --rm --detach busybox)
```

Then you can use the container id in your `docker exec` command like so:

```sh
docker exec $container_id ls -la
```

or

```sh
docker stop $container_id
```

*Note: Not using a (unique) name for the container but using an ID instead is inspired by this article on how to treat your servers/containers as [cattle and not pets](http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/)*

Answer (score 9):

I just figured out a way to do this that works for this. I'm constantly going into my container in bash, but each time I do it I have to look up the id of the running container - which is a pain. I use the `--filter` command like so:

```
docker ps -q --filter="NAME={name of container}"
```

Then the only thing that's output is the id of the container, which allows me to run:

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -q --filter="NAME={name of container}") bash
```

...which is what I really want to do in this case.

You can filter by

```
id, name, label, exited, status, ancestor, 
beforesince, volume, network, publishexpose, 
health,isolation, or is-task
```

The documentation for filter is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering).