# PHP: Get Container ID in Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, containers, php-7.2

How can I get the Docker container ID within the container itself using PHP?

I just found linux commands as [here](https://gist.github.com/nmarley/0ee3e2cf14dabfb868eb818b8b30e7e0):

```
DOCKER_CID=$(cat /proc/1/cpuset | cut -c9-)
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container

Comment: Checked. How would a PHP solution look like?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `get_env()` to get environment variables of the system.

if after running `echo $DOCKER_CID` in the CLI you get the ID you can then use this code in your PHP:

```
$docker_cid = getenv('DOCKER_CID');
```

Comment: Ok, but this solution requires to set the env-Variable first :-(

Answer (score 1):

Everyone's answers combined means that after running the following command in the cotainer:

```
DOCKER_CID=$(cat /proc/1/cpuset | cut -c9-)
```

You are able to get the id using:

```
$docker_cid = getenv('DOCKER_CID');
```

If you don't know how to run that command in a container, here are some options:

- Run it using: `docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/bash`
- Make a PHP script: `exec('DOCKER_CID=$(cat /proc/1/cpuset | cut -c9-)');` (I don't recommend that, but if someone uses this, make sure it's secure.)

Credits to Marcin, who already answered it, but maybe not clear enough.