# How to get container ID from a node process

Tags: node.js, docker

I have launched a number of docker containers with node process running inside them. Is there a way to programatically obtain the container ID in which a node process is running during runtime?

Docker version: 17.12.0-ce-mac49

Update:
Most most recent attempt hasn't worked:

```
        const cp = require('child_process');
        const output = cp.execSync('cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep devices');
        console.log(output.toString('utf8'));
```

But I get the following error:

```
   Error: Command failed: cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep devices
   cat: /proc/self/cgroup: No such file or directory

       at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:625:11)
       at Object.execSync (child_process.js:662:13)
```

The same issue is observed when using

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker, how to get container information from within the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/docker-how-to-get-container-information-from-within-the-container)

Comment: It is the default container `hostname`, and also is included in `/proc/self/cgroup`.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've updated the original question using `/proc/self/group`. But that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: How about `const os = require('os'); console.log(os.hostname());`?