# How to access container id in NodeJs application in host network mode

Tags: node.js, docker, hostname

I am trying to get a docker container's Id when network=host settings is enabled but instead of getting the containerId I am getting the host instance name. But, in case my network=host is not passed in the command it gives me the containerId as expected.
In short:

Case 1- I run my container with command – `docker run --network="host" -d -it myservice:1.0`

```
const os = require("os");
console.log(os.hostname()) /// prints **docker-desktop**
```

Case 2- I run my container with command – `docker run -d -it myservice:1.0`

```
const os = require("os");
console.log(os.hostname()) /// prints **67db4w32k112** as expected
```

Is there a way I can get the same output i.e **67db4w32k112** in case 1 as well?

Comment: Why do you need the container ID?  Why do you need host networking?  Needing either of these is a little bit unusual, so if you could for example avoid needing host networking then the `hostname()` call you describe would work.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52988227/1309377) you can probably do something like below which will read the `/proc/1/cpuset` file inside the container. This file has the current container ID, the contents look like:

```
/docker/7be92808767a667f35c8505cbf40d14e931ef6db5b0210329cf193b15ba9d605
```

This will be more reliable in your case than using `os.hostname()` since it works both with and without the `--newtwork="host"`flag on the docker run command.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('/proc/1/cpuset', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  let containerID = data.replace("/docker/", "");
  console.log(containerID);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way we can use without worrying about infrastructure. Like something that gives instanceId in case it is deployed over the normal ec2-instance, gives dockerId if deployed as docker containers?

Comment: @Lavish I do not know much about ec2-instances, might be worth it to research / ask another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a helper package such as *docker-container-id*

Add the dependency in your package.json

```
npm install --save docker-container-id
```

Here's an example:

```
const getId = require('docker-container-id');

async function() {
  console.log("I'm in container:", await getId());
}
```

[npmjs reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-container-id)