# Is there any way to get the container name inside a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way of getting the container name inside the container in a java programm using processBuilder ?

Example: the command `docker run -it --name AppContainer RetrieveNameApp`
should return `AppContainer`

Thank you !

Comment: Is this an xy problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Going along with what Don asked, why would you want a container to even know that it is dockerized?  Containers should be oblivious to it.  If you explain why you want it, maybe we can suggest a better solution or try to find an API for what you are asking for.

Comment: well this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/how-can-i-get-docker-linux-container-information-from-within-the-container-itsel

Comment: Very interesting ! I did not know that this kind of problem was theorized. In fact here I really need the name of the container from inside this same container. Thanks to @dreamcrash and some research, I created a new environment variable to be able to access the name of the container from inside and send data to a database

Answer (score 1):

*I just ran into this use case, but the examples given were `docker` centric, not to mention they wanted you to expose `docker.sock` which... it's bad form/security risk.*

Prerequisite:

```
apt update
apt install dnsutils
```

Or...

```
yum install bind-utils
```

Lastly:

```
hostname -I | xargs -L 1 -d ' ' dig +noall +answer -x | awk '{print $5}' | cut -f2 -d _ | sort | uniq
```

If you run this *inside* the *running* docker container, you'll get the name.

---

Working examples:

(**docker-compose**) *Note: you can copy this EXACTLY into your shell. This is for demonstration purposes ONLY, and i DO NOT suggest you write your `docker-compose.yaml` like this.*

```
docker-compose -f <(cat << EOF
services:
    this-is-my-name-every-body:
      image: python:3.6
EOF
) run --rm this-is-my-name-every-body bash -c "apt update &>/dev/null; apt install -y dnsutils &>/dev/null; hostname -I | xargs -L 1 -d ' ' dig +noall +answer -x | awk '{print \$5}' | cut -f2 -d _ | sort | uniq"
```

(**docker**) *Note: in order to be able to do a reverse lookup the `docker run` command MUST have a `--network`, and that requires you to `docker network create` it (must be only ran once).*

```
docker network create temp-net
docker run --rm -it --network temp-net --name hello-every-body python:3.6 bash -c "apt update &>/dev/null; apt install -y dnsutils &>/dev/null; hostname -I | xargs -L 1 -d ' ' dig +noall +answer -x | awk '{print \$5}' | cut -f2 -d _ | sort | uniq"
```

Comment: Wow! This was a wildly unknown feature of the docker DNS server!  Here's a slightly simpler one-liner for a container with a single network interface: "host $(hostname -i)" will return something like "4.0.18.172.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer cont_name_1.service_default."

Comment: @xrobau there is a lot of overlap between `host` and `dig`, the reason i chose `dig` was because it uses tabs to separate the parts of the output, making it easier to parse out. `host` unfortunately uses spaces as delimiters, and makes it more difficult. While they both arrive at the same outcome, I did make the shell command more complicated to cover my butt, in case someone was using `--scale 2` (+) and the same name was used multiple times.