# How to find container image name/ tag from inside the container

Tags: docker, container-image

Apologies in advance if this is a bad question, but is it possible to look up the name and tag of the image off of which a container is running, from inside that container?

Comment: set values into environment var with `--build-arg`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone that's not possible for my setup

Answer (score 2):

This is **not possible** currently from (07-2022), and will not be implemented.

You can implement it for example with `export IMAGE_NAME=iamawsome-V2.2.3`, during build time, so you can use this env in the image.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Adrian Antunez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46586925/5790653), you can run this command to the the container id:

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup | head -n 1 | cut -d '/' -f3
```

But it seems you cannot find the image name/tag been used. It seems it's due to security matters.

Comment: This does not answer my question - I still don't see the image name and tag.

Comment: You cannot see image name/tag as far as I know and googled

Comment: OK. Please update your answer to reflect that.