# Adding Application Container name in logs using Serilog C#

Tags: serilog

I am using load balancer in my application and want to print the container name (where my services are hosted) in application log. I am using Serilog for logging.

Do we have any enricher available for this?

Host gives me the base url but not the container name.

Help in this regards is much appreciated.

Comment: Worst case scenario you can build your own solution by getting the name of the container manually.
The name of the container is found inside the container's filesystem. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/how-can-i-get-docker-linux-container-information-from-within-the-container-itsel).