# How to get Docker Container Name inside the docker?

Tags: linux, docker

I am running a Python application inside of a `python:3.11.2-alpine` container.

The Python application needs information about the container name within the running container.

I have read about [how to get the general container information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995351/how-can-i-get-docker-linux-container-information-from-within-the-container-itsel)

Mostly the answers are how to get the container id (e.g. by environment variable `HOSTNAME`).
But there is also the need for the specific container name (see the last column in the following code block).

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND        CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS   NAMES
3b7ef8f1d979   myfancyimage:0.0.9   "/bin/sh..."   22 hours ago   Up 22 hours (unhealthy)           myfancyname
```

I have also checked the additional environment variables inside the container, but I have not found any information about the container name.

Is there a way to get the container name?

Comment: Not really, the best way is to pass the name you need as an environment variable.  Also see [1](/q/64441527), [2](/q/65332293), [3](/q/51544433), [4](/q/44253117), [5](/q/56675083); between those there is an answer using the host's Docker socket to ask the Docker API (and also potentially take over the host system), and a [clever DNS-based solution](/a/68164153).

Answer (score 0):

In my running Docker instance, running `hostname` *does* give the container name, not the container ID. In my case the name has the short-form ID appended to it for convenience, so it has the form `<my_container_name>-<shortID>`.
Could you share a code snippet showing how you are getting the ID and container names?
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification

Comment: When running the container as a devcontainer I can hit `printenv` into command line and I get the container ID (e.g `HOSTNAME=3b7ef8f1d979`). Otherwise I get `HOSTNAME` in my python application by `os.environ['HOSTNAME']`

Answer (score 0):

The [`--name`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#options) option sets a custom name to identify your container on the Docker host, the [`-h, --hostname`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#options) option sets the container's hostname.

You could set both options to get the information from the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable inside your container:

```bash
$ docker run --rm --name myfancyname -h myfancyname -it myfancyimage env
HOSTNAME=myfancyname
TERM=xterm
```

Comment: I would like to run multiple docker images by docker-compose. I would therefore be reluctant to proceed in this way for each individual container