# Get the name or ID of the current Google Compute Instance

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a number of Google Compute Engine instances that run Python code, and I want to find the name or the ID of each instance from inside the instances.

One solution I've found is to get the internal IP of the instance using:

```
import socket
internal_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Then I list all the instances:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
self.compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
result = self.compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()
```

Then I iterate over all the instances to check if the internal IP matches the IP of an instance:

```
for instance in result["items"]:
    if instance["networkInterfaces"][0]["networkIP"] == internal_ip:
        internal_id = instance["id"]
```

This works but it's a bit complicated, is there a more direct way to achieve the same thing, e.g. using Google's Python Client Library or the gcloud command line tool?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Instance Name:**

`socket.gethostname()` or `platform.node()` should return the name of the instance. You might have to do a bit of parsing depending on your OS.

This worked for me on Debian and Ubuntu systems:

```
import socket
gce_name = socket.gethostname()
```

However, on a CoreOS instance, the `hostname` command gave the name of the instance plus the zone information, so you would have to do some parsing.

**Instance ID / Name / More (Recommended):**

The better way to do this is to use the [Metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata). This is the easiest way to get instance information, and works with basically any programming language or straight CURL. Here is a Python example using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

```
import requests
metadata_server = "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/"
metadata_flavor = {'Metadata-Flavor' : 'Google'}
gce_id = requests.get(metadata_server + 'id', headers = metadata_flavor).text
gce_name = requests.get(metadata_server + 'hostname', headers = metadata_flavor).text
gce_machine_type = requests.get(metadata_server + 'machine-type', headers = metadata_flavor).text
```

Again, you might need to do some parsing here, but it is really straightforward!

References:
[How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Excellent answer - thanks. In case the zone is needed, then (using this answer), `requests.get(metadata_server + 'zone', headers = metadata_flavor).text` can be used.

Answer (score 12):

To get your instance name, execute the following from your VM:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/hostname -H Metadata-Flavor:Google
```

and to get your instance id:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id -H Metadata-Flavor:Google
```

Check out the documentations for other available parameters: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#project_and_instance_metadata