# Set Folder Path base on Machine Hostname in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple **if-check** in python.
I check for a certain hostname and set path accordingly.

But the result is unexplainable to me.

```
hostname = os.system('hostname')

if(hostname == 'rkim'):
    path = '/home/forge/rkim-web-app/'
    # This block of code should be running 
else:
    path = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/rkim-web-app/'
    # But this block of code run instead
```

**Result :**

```
python /home/forge/rkim-web-app/database/backup_mysql.py

rkim <-------- hostname printed == rkim 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/forge/rkim-web-app/database/backup_mysql.py", line 28, in <module>
    file = open(path + '.env', "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/rkim-web-app/.env'
```

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: From `os.system`'s documentation: "the return value is the exit status of the process"

Comment: `hostname` isn't what you think it is

Comment: @Cfreak : Why is it print like that ?

Comment: @spectras : what is the possible alternative then ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/rkim-web-app/.env` exist on my Mac OS X.

Comment: `/home/forge/rkim-web-app/` exist in my VM Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

os.system('command') seems to return exit status but prints the hostname. Instead of os module, use platform module to get the host name.

```
import platform 
hostname = platform.node()

if(hostname == 'rkim'):
    path = '/home/forge/rkim-web-app/'
else:
    path = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/rkim-web-app/'
```

Comment: Will I need to install any extra module on my linux machine or Mac OS to use this code ??

Comment: Also, do you mean `host = platform.node()` ? or `hostname = platform.node()` ?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname

Comment: Thanks. Just checking. :D