# Add custom title text to jupyter notebook interface

Tags: config, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I frequently run `jupyter notebook` on multiple servers/computers, and it would be great if the interface could be customised so I can see at a glance which server/computer is behind the notebook GUI I'm looking at.

Is there a setting for adding a short piece of text to the title bar in the web interface? Can someone suggest a snippet of code to put in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`?

Comment: I found a hacky workaround: edit the file `templates/page.html` (in my case it was in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/`), look for 'logo.png' and add your text to the html. I chose to add it just before the `<a ...>` tag for the logo.

Answer (score 0):

most flexible would be:

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

answered in :
[How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname/4271755#4271755)

Comment: A link would be handy. I believe the answer to which you are referring is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271755

Comment: Please do not link to other answers without explaining why the question is different but the answer still helpful. If the question IS identical please flag as duplicate instead.