# Get hostname for network device using Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I am trying to find the switch port that a network device (e.g. server) is plugged into (i.e. the hostname) and MAC address for the device (e.g. server). I can connect to the device just fine knowing the IP as follows:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(self.TIMEOUT)
sock.connect_ex((ip_address, DEFAULT_PORT))
```

How do I get the MAC address and port name/number? The switches are Cisco but I don't want to rely on apriori knowledge about the network hardware.

Answer (score 0):

```
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

[How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It gives me my machine hostname Mortons-iMac.local. I want the switch port which I know is S14M12.