# Raspberry Pi Python run program from path

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am currently trying to get a Python program to autostart on my Raspberry Pi. The problem is, that the program is reading in a config file, which is located in the same folder as the program itself. So when I run the Program from IDE, it works fine.

If I try to run it from the console (or rc.local) it doesn't find the config file. If I cd into the folder and try to run it, it works fine again.

So how can I tell Python or rc.local to run from inside the folder? I have tried to goolge for a solution, but couldn't find one.

I don't want to adress the config file with it's complete path, because I program and debug on my PC, but use the program on the raspberry, so I would have to change the path every time I switch between devices.

Hopefully someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered putting the config file somewhere in `/etc/...` and reading it with an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several possible approaches here:

- On the raspberry pi, you can `cd` to the correct directory before running the python program: `cd <destination dir> && python your_program.py`, or write a two-line shell script to to this.
- Pass an optional command line argument to python that contains the absolute path to the config file. If no argument is given, use the current path.
- Try to auto-detect the environment that the python program is running in (e.g. using `gethostname()` or by setting an environment variable [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)).

Comment: Yeah, I usually use a shell script for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
config_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), f'{config_filename})
```

will get you the FQN for the config based on where the script is located, works in all environments