# python create txt file with hostname name

Tags: python, export, hostname, txt

I have a py script which creates txt file with some name, but i need that it named it with hostname. for ex
when it creates txt file from test1 hostname it gave name to this txt file test1.txt

this is script. how to change it?

```
def save_passwords(self):
    with open('test.txt','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.writelines(self.passwordList)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would look like this:

```
import socket

def save_passwords(self):     
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    with open(hostname + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
        f.writelines(self.passwordList)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't work. It sais failed to execute script

Comment: it doesn't give any error. it just names it as it was. nothing changed

Comment: Can I see the code in context? I'm confused as the code doesn't allow for it to name the file what it was.

Comment: I've updated your code with the changes I showed in the answer. Try this: https://pastebin.com/n2yRr14B. I've added comments on the lines I've changed.

Comment: and can you change that it exportied txt file with hidden?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want the file created to be hidden? Also, if the original question was solved make sure to mark it as correct.

Comment: I checked original file which you edited and it works. great. thanks.

Comment: yes i mean file which is created txt was hidden

Comment: Different operating systems hide files in different ways. Looks like you're building this program for Windows. This code should hide the file in Windows: `subprocess.check_call(["attrib","+H",hostname + ".txt"])` Make sure `import subprocess` is at the top of the your file.

Comment: yes for windows. can you edit whole script with that?

Comment: Yes, you can change the file save location. For network sharing, you should open a new question as that falls outside the question.