# python use os.path.join to take specific location

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path

I need to save a folder called D:\MyPc if the hostname is MyPc

```
name_file = open("D:/Others/name.txt" , "r")
data = name_file.readline()
name_file.close()
print(os.path.join("D:\", data))
```

the output is D:
MyPc

Comment: what is the problem ? That is very unclear what you expect

Comment: What is in `data`? I'm surprised that `"D:\"` parsed, but if `data` is a fully qualified path name, the join won't change it.

Comment: Instead of opening a file we don't have access to, just initialize `data` to something that we can test. The code you post will raise a syntax error and I don't see any way that it could produce the output shown.

Comment: The variable data is not important i just need to group them without space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the hostname: [How can I use Python to get the system hostname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271740/how-can-i-use-python-to-get-the-system-hostname)

Also, there is an error in your code. Change the last line to have double backslash in string:

```
print(os.path.join("D:\\", data))
```